# Convert label-based index (loc) to position-based index (iloc)

Tags: python, pandas

Given my data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': [11, 12, 13],
        'y': [21, 22, 23]
    },
    index=['a', 'b', 'c']
)
```

I want to find the positional index corresponding to the labels `['a', 'c']`. I know from visual inspection that they are `[0, 2]`, but this is only possible in toy examples.

The "brute force" method is

```py
my_lab = ['a', 'c']
my_pos = (data.index == my_idx).to_numpy().nonzero()[0]
```

Is there a better/faster/more-elegant way to do this? Or is the brute force method the only method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
my_pos = data.index.get_indexer(my_lab)
print (my_pos)
[0 2]
```

Or [`Index.searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html):

```
my_pos = data.index.searchsorted(my_lab)
print (my_pos)
[0 2]
```